# Capture waypoints - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, cookies

Using the Google Maps API I am successfully able to enter a route with multiple waypoints and calculate the total journey distance. I can record and set as cookies the start and end points but have not been able to do the same with the waypoints. Any ideas on how to limit the waypoints to a maximum of three and then record what they are and set to cookies would be great.

```
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var map_center;
var map_zoom;

//initialize Google Map API onload
$(function(){ 
    initialize();  
});


//calls to make after finishing complete page load
$(document).ready(function(){

    //call on form submit
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        $("#loader").html('&nbsp;<span class="label label-info">Loading...</span>');
        calcRoute();
        return false;
    });

// Hack for loading Map properly when opened from Modal box
$('#mapModal').on('shown', function () {
    map_center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

    map.setCenter(map_center);
    map.setZoom(map_zoom);
  });
});

// Initialize google map object
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.210619,0.173573),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

apply_autocomplete($("#fromAddress")[0]);
apply_autocomplete($("#toAddress")[0]);
}


// Apply Autocomplete API
function apply_autocomplete(input){
var options = {
    types: ['geocode']
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
}


// Use this function to set Waypoint
function setDirections() 
{
//create waypoints array & fill it with all locations entered by user
var waypoints = new Array();

waypoints[0] = $("#fromAddress").val();
waypoints[1] = $("#toAddress").val();
var waypoints_counter=2;

$('input[name="toWaypoints[]"]').each(function()
{
    waypoints[waypoints_counter]=$(this).val();
    waypoints_counter++;
});


//this is the main google API function that generates the directions
gdir.loadFromWaypoints(waypoints);
}


// Calculate route and directions
function calcRoute() {
//create waypoints array & fill it with all locations entered by user
var waypts = new Array();

var start_address = $("#fromAddress").val();
var end_address = $("#toAddress").val();

$('input[name="toWaypoints[]"]').each(function()
{
    waypts.push({
        location:$(this).val(),
        stopover:true
    });
});

// Create a Request variable for Map
var request = {
    origin: start_address,
    destination: end_address,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};


//KS Set the destination as a cookie
document.cookie = "origin=" + start_address;
document.cookie = "destination=" + end_address;
//KS set waypoint cookie (does not work here!)
//document.cookie = "waypoints=" + waypoints;


// Execute the Route Method to generate Direction Route on Map
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    var directionsDiv = document.getElementById('directions');

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDiv.innerHTML = "";
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(directionsDiv);
        $(directionsDiv).addClass('well');

        var route = response.routes[0];

        // calculate total distance and duration
        var distance = 0;
        var time = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<route.legs.length; i++) {
            var theLeg = route.legs[i];
            distance += theLeg.distance.value;
            time += theLeg.duration.value;
        }

        //display summary into summary block
        total_summary = '<div class="alert alert-info">';
        total_summary += '  <strong>Total Distance : </strong>' + showDistance(distance) + " ( about " + Math.round(time/60) + " minutes)" + '<br><br>';
        total_summary += '  <a id="show_map" href="#mapModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-white"></i>Show Map &amp; Directions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="bookTaxi2.php" role="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-white"></i>Get Quote</a>';
        total_summary += '</div>';
        $("#summary").html(total_summary);

        map_zoom = map.getZoom();

        $("#loader").html('');

//KS Set the distance as a cookie
document.cookie = "miles=" + showMiles(distance);

    }
    else {
        var statusText = getDirectionStatusText(status);
        directionsDiv.innerHTML = "An error occurred - " + statusText;
    }
  });
}

// Show distance in different measurements
function showDistance(distance) {

return Math.round((distance*0.621371192)/100) / 10 + " miles (" + Math.round(distance/100) / 10 + " km)";

}

//KS Get distance in miles for calculations
function showMiles(distance) {

return Math.round((distance*0.621371192)/100) / 10 ;

}

// Get the Map direction status message
function getDirectionStatusText(status){
  switch(status){
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST :
        return "Invalid request";
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED :
        return "Maximum waypoints exceeded";
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND :
        return "Not found";
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT :
        return "Over query limit";
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.REQUEST_DENIED :
        return "Request denied";
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR :
        return "Unknown error";
    case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS :
        return "Zero results";
    default:
        return status;
  }
}


// Add More waypoints
function add_waypoint()
{
  waypoint_container = '<div class="control-group ">';
  waypoint_container+= '  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Calling at : </label>';
waypoint_container+= '  <div class="controls">';
waypoint_container+= '      <input type="text" id="toWaypoints" name="toWaypoints[]" class="input-xlarge" value="">';
waypoint_container+= '      &nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="return add_waypoint();">Add another | </a>';
waypoint_container+= '      &nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="return remove_waypoint(this);">Remove</a>';
waypoint_container+= '  </div>';
waypoint_container+= '</div>';

$('.destination-container').before(waypoint_container);

$('[name=toWaypoints\\[\\]]').each(function() {
    apply_autocomplete($(this)[0]);

});

return false;
}

// Remove waypoint
function remove_waypoint(obj)
{
$(obj).parent().parent().remove();
return false;
}
```

Comment: `gdir.loadFromWaypoints(waypoints);`  is a [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services#RoutesAndSteps) function, that version of the API is deprecated and has been turned off.

Comment: ah, I thought I was on v3. I will upgrade and retry - thank you

Comment: Most of your code is v3, but that function doesn't exist.  If it is actually being run, you should get an obvious javascript error.